# How to get notification when file is uploaded in server?

Tags: android, phpmyadmin

I am new to Android Studio and I am developing an application like College Management System.

Basically, in my app, there are two logins- one for faculty and one for students.If any faculty uploading any file to the server, then on student side on the same time they should get a notification.

Not sure where to start, so any suggestion about where to look would be really appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Simplest way send notifications using firebase

Comment: thanks, but i am working on 000webhosting. It is compulsory to use firebase ?@BrunoFerreira

Comment: use firebase api to create and send notifications using php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).

Specifically you'd need [Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/products/cloud-messaging/) and maybe [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth/).

Both services are **completely free** and easy to set up (especially if you're developing using Android Studio, because it is integrated with Firebase and allows you to copy/paste code already configured for your FB account).

There's also a well made [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/).

And if your college wants something more the prices are [really cheap](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/).

P.S.

I'm no way affiliated with Firebase or Google.

Comment: Thanks, i am also not affiliated with Firebase. So, is there  any other way?like php @Vincenzo Strumbo.

Comment: Firebase is mandatory for android push notification, so at least for the notification part of your app you have to use it. Then you can use other ways to invoke the notification api, like php as suggested in other comments, but you still need to have a firebase project connected to your app.